# How do you polar-plot the complex-valued array factor (AF) of a phased antenna array?

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, complex-numbers, antennas

If a normalized array factor for an $N$-element linear antenna array (without per-element phase shifts) is calculated as
$$
AF = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{m=0}^{N-1} e^{jmkd\cos\theta}
$$
where:

- $\theta$ is the beam angle,
- $m$ is the element number
- $k$ is the wavelength-phase component ($k=2\pi/\lambda)$,
- $d$ is the spacing between elements

then how do I plot in terms of $\theta$ since $j$ is going to give complex results for the polar radius?

For a trivial case where $N=2$, $m=1$, $\lambda=1$, $d=\lambda$, and evaluating $\theta=30^{\circ}$,
$$
e^{j2\pi\cos(30)}  \approx 0.67−0.76j
$$
For the purposes of plotting, do I throw away the imaginary value or take the complex absolute value (modulus)?

Comment: plot $|AF|^2$ (or $20log|AF|$ (dB)) vs. $\theta$, the phase of $AF$ does not matter in this context

Comment: $|AF|$ always gives a value of 1.  I think this makes sense because the radius is 1, ie, $r e^{j\theta}$. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: Oh, I got it!  I was doing $|AF|$ of a single element, not of the whole sum.  If you post an answer I'll check it :)

Comment: @hyportnex, what does $|AF|^2$ do?  I think it gives me the best plot: Everything is scaled nicely from 0-1, though I'd like to understand why.

Comment: $|AF|^2$ is the power (flux) density in the $\theta$ direction. Usually it is plotted normalized relative to some particular $\theta = \theta_0$ value, most often $\theta_0=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per hyportnex's comment, which also provides the answer:

- Plot $|AF|^2$ (or $20\log|AF|$ (dB)) vs. θ, the phase of AF does not matter in this context.  $|AF|^2$ is the power (flux) density in the θ direction. Usually it is plotted normalized relative to some particular $θ=θ_0$ value, most often $θ_0=0$